# When I Try To Render My Image It Comes Out Blank

Tags: rendering

Every time I go to render my image it comes out looking like the image provided. I even tried to copy the model from one scene to another to see if it was my scene that was bugged.

I only have one camera in the scene. I'm rendering with Eevee.